# System.Kind returns inconsistent results in File Explorer and Storage file Queries in UWP

Tags: windows, winapi, uwp

I have an app which queries files and folders properly when running on a `windows 10 Pro machine 18363` with the OS language being `English UK`. Of interest in the queries is the use of `System.Kind` which is used in the app as well as in `File Explorer search`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers-user-friendly-kind-names
https://learn.microsoft.com/en/windows/win32/properties/props-system-kind

Running such queries, either via the uwp app or File Explorer returns wrong results on another machine which has the same build but is a `Windows 10 Family` with the OS language being `French`. The docs says that the strings are not localized, and this sentence is confusing.

I get the following results when running the queries on a folder in the desktop containing pictures and videos and text files:

System.Kind:picture **Returns Pictures; hence OK**

System.Kind:video **Returns Videos; hence OK**

System.Kind:video OR System.Kind:picture **Returns Only pictures, NOT OK**

System.Kind:picture OR System.Kind:video **Returns Only pictures, NOT OK**

And the following is even more strange

System.Kind:image OR System.Kind:video **Returns Only pictures, NOT OK**

System.Kind:video OR System.Kind:image **Returns Videos OR pictures, hence OK**

I also tried changing the **OR** for a french **OU**, but that did not help.

The UWP should query for any language OS environment with a universal approach without localizing the query string, and to me this is why `System.Kind` is preferred over `kind`(English) or `sorte` (French).

From the System.Kind enum I should use **picture** or **video**, but this fails in a French OS and **image** works only in one order

1) How can I set the queries above in a language invariant way?

2) Why the last two operations are NOT commutative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.Kind is an [enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/search/-search-3x-advancedquerysyntax#examples-1), so the canonical syntax is:

`System.Kind:System.Kind#Picture OR System.Kind:System.Kind#Video`

Anything else returns weird results on localized Windows versions, for some reason :-)

`System.Kind#Picture` corresponds to what's explained in the documentation:

> For a defined semantic type T with values or ranges named N₁ through
>   Nₖ, the canonical syntax for the ith value or range is the canonical
>   name for T, followed by the character #, followed by Ni

Comment: Thanks very much, I will check this tonight but respond only tomorrow to test it on the french pc: Do you mind explaining why we need to double the System.Kind in the syntax? i.e System.Kind:System.Kind#Picture vs something like System.Kind:Picture?

Comment: And .. is System.Photo.DateTaken:2019 canonical? I have doubts now. What about languages that use another numeric system, would that fail?

Comment: The link provided is under the section Windows 7, is it safe to assume this is also for windows 10?

Comment: I have updated my answer. For Windows 10, yes, the documentation speaks about Windows 7 from a Windows Vista perspective (Windows Property System appeared with Windows Vista.) As for dates handling... a whole world is hidden behind: https://superuser.com/questions/119906/search-for-files-after-a-relative-date-using-windows-search

Comment: Thanks Simon, that works now. I will figure out for the dates, too.